# How to fix 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException' in Hive-Spark, when using simple query?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hive-query

I am trying to perform a simple query on Hive - Spark engine:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM classification_output GROUP BY model_id;
```

I keep receiving the below error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to get a spark session: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Failed to create spark client. (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Only ONT time it worked after 12 minutes

The number of records on the table are around ~7K, I suspect a configuration issue, but I am not sure which parameter.

I tried to:

- Restart HIVE server
- Increased the timeout for Hive server

Note:

Using:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM classification_output;
```

With no `group by....` works just fine and return the below:

```
+-------+
|  _c0  |
+-------+
| 7164  |
+-------+
1 row selected (0.092 seconds)
```

Comment: Query is logically incorrect, why "group by" used if total count is required. If include groupped field into "select", all have to work fine, smth. like: SELECT model_id, count(*) FROM classification_output GROUP BY model_id

Comment: That exactly what I am looking for? To group by model_id not to get the count. However, if I removed the group by it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time around this issue, I managed to find the solution. It has nothing to do with the query. There was another SparkClient process running, once I stopped it and executed the query it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that lands here with the error

`Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement:FAILED: SemanticException Got exception though getTableObjectByName method should ignore it`

check your authentication.